# In javascript how to change the below date format

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a date format which is `181221171403`

```
18-year
12-month
21-day
17-hour
14-minute
03-second
```

How to convert the below format.

```
December 21st 2018, 17:14:03.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = '181221171403';
var dateArr = str.match(/.{1,2}/g); // given ["18", "12", "21", "17", "14", "03"]
var strDate = '20'+dateArr[0]+'-'+dateArr[1]+'-'+dateArr[2]+' '+dateArr[3]+':'+dateArr[4]+':'+dateArr[5];
var d = new Date(strDate);

const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

// December 21st 2018, 17:14:03.000
const res = monthNames[d.getMonth()]+' '+d.getDate()+' '+d.getFullYear()+' '+d.getFullYear()+' '+d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes()+':'+d.getSeconds()+'.000';
console.log(res);
```

And after you can generate the date with the format shouaite using the objectv Date of JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment.js for this job. More in [moment documentation](http://momentjs.com/)

```js
var stringDate = '181221171403';
var date = moment(stringDate, 'YYMMDDHHmmss');
console.log(date.format('MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```